# turborepo package unexpected token export

Tags: typescript, turborepo

I have a custom package named project-types where i share my types between packages

and when i import the simple class into my nestjs project typescript compiles it just fine, but when it comes to runtime and executing the javascript it sais:

```
server:dev: D:\Program\net-autism\packages\project-types\index.ts:1
server:dev: export * from "./authentication";     
server:dev: ^^^^^^
server:dev: 
server:dev: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
server:dev:     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
server:dev:     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
server:dev:     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
server:dev:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)      
server:dev:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-types",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "types": "./index.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint *.ts*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-custom": "*",
    "tsconfig": "*",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2"
  }
}
```

usage:

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoginDto } from 'project-types';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor() {}

  @Post('login')
  async login(@Body() credentials: LoginDto) {}

  @Post('register')
  async register() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better solution is to do what @Patrick Kenyon did,

and add in your ts-config this :

Your package tsconfig.json :

```json
   "compilerOptions":{
   ...
   "paths": {
     "your_package_name": ["./src/index"]
   }
```

Your App tsconfig.json

```json
   "compilerOptions":{
   ...
    "paths": {

           "dto": ["../../../packages/your_package_name/src/index.ts"]
       }
```

Answer (score 16):

I've also just come up against this problem. From what I can tell when you build your consuming app it isn't transpiling the Typescript from your types package.

For NextJS projects there is an npm package which addresses this issue https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules

However, as I have a NestJS project you'll need to transpile the types package yourself. This is my set up:

**packages/project-types/package.json**

```
{
  ...
  // entry point is now the transpiled version of your code
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
  ...
}
```

**packages/project-types/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "include": ["."],
  "exclude": ["dist", "build", "node_modules"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

**apps/nest-project/tsconfig.json**

```
{
  ...
  "module": "commonjs",
  ...
}
```

You can then configure your `turbo.json` to ensure that all dependent packages are built beforehand [topological dependencies](https://turborepo.org/docs/core-concepts/pipelines#topological-dependency). Example taken from the Turbo docs:

```
  "pipeline": {
    "build": {
      // "A package's `build` command depends on its dependencies'
      // and devDependencies' `build` commands being completed first"
      "dependsOn": ["^build"]
    }
    // ... omitted for brevity
  }
```

Hope that helps.

[Update]

Example [repo](https://github.com/patrickkenyon/turbo-example)

Comment: please send document links of this so i may understand it properly

Comment: Example [repo](https://github.com/patrickkenyon/turbo-example)

Comment: Is there a way to avoid have to compile the shared types beforehand? in my example repo https://github.com/jacobdo2/types-nestjs-nextjs-turbo , you are able to import interfaces, types from common package, but once you want to access a value of enum, it throws the unexpected token export error at the entry point to the types package.

Comment: @Jacobdo `enum`'s are a set of defined values and are not in fact types [TS Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). This means that they are included in the transpiled (or built) version of your NestJS project in your example. If you check the `apps/api/dist` directory you'll notice that there isn't any reference to your interface named `Example` whilst `ExampleEnum` is included. If you want to avoid having to transpile this package before use, you'll just need to ensure you're only using types.